# Changing struct values when stepping into library

Tags: c, gcc

A function is being called (C99) in a library that's being statically linked to.

In tests.c:

`int ok = solve_equation(&eq, &result);`

In poly.c:

`int solve_equation(equation_integer_2 *eq, fraction *result) {...}`

A pointer is passed to the struct variable, "eq", into the function. When gdb steps into the function, the value of one of the struct's variables 
`eq->poly->term3->coefficient`
is different than it just was. The value seems to have been changed going from calling code to library. Is this right? What could be causing the change?

Gdb output:

```
Breakpoint 1, test_solve_equation_1 () at tests.c:97
97      int ok = solve_equation(&eq, &result);
(gdb) p &eq->poly->term1->coefficient
$15 = (unsigned char *) 0x7fffffffd880 ""
(gdb) p &eq->poly->term2->coefficient
$16 = (unsigned char *) 0x7fffffffd890 "\002\001@"
(gdb) p &eq->poly->term3->coefficient
$17 = (unsigned char *) 0x7fffffffd8a0 ""
(gdb) s
solve_equation (eq=0x7fffffffd8f0, result=0x7fffffffd8d0) at poly.c:64
64          if (eq->poly->term1->coefficient == 0 && eq->poly->term3->coefficient == 0) {
(gdb) p &eq->poly->term1->coefficient
$18 = (unsigned char *) 0x7fffffffd880 ""
(gdb) p &eq->poly->term2->coefficient
$19 = (unsigned char *) 0x7fffffffd890 "\002\001@"
(gdb) p &eq->poly->term3->coefficient
$20 = (unsigned char *) 0x7fffffffd8a0 "\320\330\377\377\377\177"
```

The term(n) structs are constructed like this:

```
void term_integer_factory(term_integer *t)                                                                                         |#include "number.h"
{                                                                                                                                  |
    t->coefficient = 0;                                                                                                            |typedef struct term_fraction
    t->degree = 1;                                                                                                                 |{
}
```

Comment: It looks like the pointers involved are somewhere on the stack. Are you sure they are valid, and not dangling pointers to local variables in functions which have since returned?

Comment: One possibility is hat the function expects a different set of parameters than the caller provides (for example, fewer parameters). The function would then use presumably free stack space which is in reality occupied by the caller's parameters. This could happen when the headers belong to a different library version than the library's binaries.

Comment: @DanielH, I've updated the question with how the structs are being set with the values. Would 0 and 1 be considered local variables in this case?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, thanks, I didn't know that could happen. I have checked for this and the parameters are matching.

Comment: The text "\320...." can be written in hexadecimal: "\xD0\xD8\xFF\xFF\xFF\x7F". That looks similar to `&result`. Please show us the entire struct definition and initialization code.

Comment: @user5329483 I hadn't spotted that, thanks. I have edited the question with my own correction of the error, as you hint the error in initialization of the struct, in this case, of the parent struct. I have malloc'd it and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Like Daniel and user5329483 hinted, the problem was in the struct initialization. There was nested struct initialization inside of a function. I've changed it to malloc all relevant structs (with the corresponding `free` calls) and it works.

It was initialized like this:

```
void polynomial_integer_2_factory(polynomial_integer_2 *p) 
{
    term_integer t1;
    term_integer_factory(&t1);
    t1.degree = 2;
    p->term1 = &t1;
    term_integer t2;
    term_integer_factory(&t2);
    t2.degree = 1;
    p->term2 = &t2;
    term_integer t3;
    term_integer_factory(&t3);
    t3.degree = 0;
    p->term3 = &t3;
}
```

Now it's initialized like this:

```
polynomial_integer_2* create_polynomial_integer_2() 
    polynomial_integer_2 *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (!p) {}
    term_integer *t1 = create_term_integer();
    t1->degree = 2;
    p->term1 = t1;
    term_integer *t2 = create_term_integer();
    t2->degree = 1;
    p->term2 = t2;
    term_integer *t3 = create_term_integer();
    t3->degree = 0;
    p->term3 = t3;
    return p;
}
```